# How to get indivisual html file from "segments" which i got after crwal in nutch?

Tags: java, linux, indexing, web-crawler, nutch

I am new to nuth.I have used nutch to crawl some domain.Now i need to get all html file corresponding to the domain in a separate folder.I have got the output from crawler as crawler/linkdb,crawler/crawldb and crawler/segments.Now please help me to proceed through commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command:

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump <segmentDir> <outputDir>
```

and replace segmentDir and outputDir with your segment and output directories (without '<')